# Python 3.x: ' '.join() on sys.stdin.readlines() Input Does Not Return Final String When Final Character Is Not a Line/Carriage Break

Tags: python, arrays, string

I'd like to convert a chunk of text, be it a single line or multiple lines, into a single string with one remaining white space `" "` at the end.

This is my code:

```
# Take a block of text as input.
print("Input Your Sentence(s) Below (and Then Hit CTRL+D):")
samp_sent = sys.stdin.readlines()

samp_sent = ' '.join(samp_sent)
samp_sent = samp_sent.replace("\n", " ")
print(samp_sent)
```

If the final character is not a line break, it omits the string and just adds the `" "`.

#### Examples (Input → Output)：

1. `"Here is one line. \n Here is another line. \n"` → `"Here is one line. Here is another line. "`
2. `"Here is one line. \n Here is another line."` → `"Here is one line. "`
3. `"Here is one line."` → `" "`

No matter if I type examples (1), (2), or (3) as input, how can I make sure that the final line will always appear in `print(samp_sent)`?

Comment: Mind asking why are you using `sys.stdin.readlines()` instead of `input()` ?

Comment: Your code works on Linux are you running on another platform?

Comment: Yes, I'm on Windows 8.

Comment: I'm a newbie with Python, so didn't know about input(). I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

If do not need white space at the beginning or end of a line, you can do:

```
samp_sent = ' '.join(line.strip() for line in samp_sent)
```

instead of

```
samp_sent = ' '.join(samp_sent)
samp_sent = samp_sent.replace("\n", " ")
```

another alternative:

```
print("Input Your Sentence(s) Below (and Then Hit CTRL+D):")
samp_sent = ' '.join(sys.stdin.read().splitlines())
print(samp_sent)
```

Comment: @MaxNoe Thanks for the hint. Added one more alternative way to do it.